# Adding expiry time in javascript

Tags: javascript, security, firefox-addon

I want to know how to add logout feature after certain expiry time in javascript.  Can somenody please tell me how to do this. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this using JavaScript and not your server-side language (IE: PHP, ASP.NET, etc)?

Comment: I'd agree with Justin, it's far safer to do this server side. Could you add a little detail about your architecture? How sessions are persisted, etc.

Comment: @Justin I am working on adding security for a jsp login page using a firefox extension. And while learning how to make firefox extension i found that i have to do it in javascript that's why i asked you in javascript. Can you please tel me the way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea you could use:

1. Add a "Last Seen" column to your User table. Update this value to the current timestamp whenever the authenticated user requests a page.
2. On the server, whenever a page is requested that requires a login, check to see if the current time is within a given threshold of the "Last Seen" time. If it isn't show the login page.
3. In addition to this, use `setTimeout` and AJAX in Javascript to query the server after the threshold amount of time has elapsed. Based on the response, either destroy the session and redirect to the login page, or do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Add a timeout with `setTimeout()`. Note that it's trivial to remove such a timer for a cracker, so it's more of a comfort than a security feature.

If security is your concern, you must do this on the server side.

If your question is "how can I logout from, say, GMail", the solution is probably to add some JavaScript to the page with Greasemonkey and assign the URL which you can find behind the "logout" link to `window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to use JavaScript and server side code (ASP.Net) to either log the user out or warn them that their session is going to expire. I've implemented something similar to this in an e-commerce application. It seems to work well.

http://blog.oscarscode.com/dot-net/display-session-timeout-warning-with-asp-net-ajax/